# Signed Assembly - Could not load Type xxxx

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly

I have a asp.net project that references some other projects in my solution. A few days ago, I signed the Referenced Assemblies (No password, just adding a key in Visual Studio). Ever since then, all new Classes I've added to the Signed Assembly, throws the normal "Could not load Type xxxx" exception. My Web project does not have a key and is not signed.

Its definitely the signing that's causing it. Unfortunately , I do need to sign them as Sharepoint only allows Signed assemblies.

Anyone else seen this?

Comment: Please show complete error. If type is loaded from signed assembly error should look different (type+assembly name should be much longer).

Comment: You can't reference unsigned assembly from a signed assembly, so make sure you are not doing it.

Comment: Hi Coder. It's not directly referenced. The Signed Assembly is referenced by a WCF Service.